# How to tell if a db update was successful?

Tags: database, asp-classic

I'm trying to modify some legacy ASP classic code, and I don't know much about ASP.  How do I tell if a database Insert, Update, or Delete failed?  By 'failed', I mean it either threw an error or affected zero rows.

Here's the code that was already in the ASP file that sets up the database connection:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=dbname;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpw;"
```

There are a few Select statements that work like:

```
qry =  "select stuff here..."
Set objRs = objConn.Execute(qry)
```

I understand how to get the results from the Select statements, but how do I get the results of a non-Select statement?  Using a result set doesn't seem like it'd be the right way to do it.  Or is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the first `Execute` method parameter to get the rows affected:

```
On Error resume next
Dim RecordsAffected as long
Dim cmd
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString()
cmd.CommandText = "Select stuff here"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

cmd.Execute RecordsAffected, , adExecuteNoRecords
If err.number > 0 or RecordsAffected = 0 then
    Response.Write "No record affected or SQL error or something"
end if
```

Using `adExecuteNoRecords` will gain performance according [to](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14433) [several](http://www.asp101.com/tips/index.asp?id=85) [sources](http://www.a1vbcode.com/vbtip-131.asp)

Source: [Execute method in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a transaction.

```
<%@Transaction="REQUIRES_NEW"  Language="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%Option Explicit%>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<%

'Perform Work
'Database Operation #1
'Database Operation #2

Sub OnTransactionCommit
    Response.Write "<H1>Success!</H1>"
End Sub

Sub OnTransactionAbort
    Response.Write "<H1>Failure!</H1>"
End Sub
%>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

For INSERTs and UPDATEs the execution will return the number of rows affected, unless you set NO COUNT ON in your stored procedures. When you define a Command object calling its ExecuteNonQuery method will return that number to you. I use the return of those numbers (and whether they're non-zero) as an indication that it worked.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is not a method in ADO classic

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

```
con.execute Sql,RecordsAffected
```

where,
`con` is Connection
`Sql` is your Command String
`RecordsAffected` is count of Records Affected