# Classic ASP mysql INSERT getting result Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have this code:

```
Set oConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

oConnection.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=localhost;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;DATABASE=xxxx; OPTION=3;"
    Sqltemp = "INSERT INTO rsvptable (fname, lname, fbid, rsvp, streetaddress, city, state, zip, streetaddress2, cellphone, acode) " & _
              "VALUES ('" & firstName & "', '" & lastName & "', " & fb & ", 0, '" & address1 & "', '" & city & "', '" & strState & "', " & zip & ", '" & address2 & "', " & cell & ", " & returnedNums & ")"

set newAdd = oConnection.execute(Sqltemp)

if newAdd.EOF then
   response.write "end"
else
   response.write "not end"
end if
```

And it keeps telling me this:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
>
> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
>
> /add.asp, line 136

line 136 is this:

```
if newAdd.EOF then
```

What would i be overlooking here?

**UPDATE**

found my answer here! :o)

[How to tell if a db update was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878577/how-to-tell-if-a-db-update-was-successful)

Comment: +1 - always good to see people finding a solution to their own problem - and it's always better to use the Command object when possible – so kudos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things:

1. you define `oRecordset` as the recordset, but then use & check eof on `newAdd`
2. Why are you trying to populate a recordet from an insert query?

Comment: `oConnection.execute(Sqltemp, rowsModified)` or something like that. I'm not good at VB. Then check `rowsModified`, it has to be 1 if the insert succeeded. 0 if it failed (in which case you will get an error actually).

Comment: Its saying now **Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub oConnection.execute(Sqltemp,intAffectedRows)**

Comment: `oConnection.execute Sqltemp,intAffectedRows` maybe. Like I said, I don't know VB, but I know Google and I know ADODB.Connection from back when I accessed it through COM from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_conn_execute.asp

> The results are stored in a new Recordset object if it is a
>   row-returning query. A closed Recordset object will be returned if it
>   is not a row-returning query.

INSERT is not a row-returning query, thus it returns a closed recordset, thus you can't `.EOF` it. Check the Rows Affected bu passing a variable as the second argument to `Execute`. If RowsAffected is 1, then you're set.