# VB6 RecordsAffected returns -1 value after .Execute method

Tags: vb6, ado

I am trying to fix an old VB6 Application error. When I try to save/insert data into database the **RecordsAffected** returns a value of **-1**. 
I try to insert message box before and after **.Execute** method. Before the **.Execute** method the value is +1 and after **.Execute** command the value returns -1. You guys have idea why it returns -1? I don't know if it is the **RecordsAffected** or **Options** parameter returns a negative value.

```
Private Function jsSave() As Boolean
Dim Cmd(0 To 1) As New ADODB.Command
Dim Prm(0 To 1, 0 To 14) As New ADODB.Parameter
Dim RetVal As Long
Dim Succeeded As Long
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo R
Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
If Me.Toolbar.Buttons("secure").Image = "lock" Then
Err.Raise 1000, , "This record is currently in lock state. You cannot alter anything in this record unless you first unlock it. For more details how to unlock this record, please refer to IT."
End If
RetVal = 1
Succeeded = 0
No = Me.txtSONo.Text    'SONo
DtlId = GetLastNo(35)    'SODtlId
'------Start Saving Main-------------------------------------------------------
Select Case CurrentStatus
Case adInsert
    Id = GetLastNo(33) + 1       'PO Id
    With Cmd(0)
        .ActiveConnection = Conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tb_SO (" _
                        & "SONo," _
                        & "SId," _
                        & "PId," _
                        & "totAmt," _
                        & "advAmt," _
                        & "Prepared," _
                        & "Recommended," _
                        & "Approved," _
                        & "Noted," _
                        & "Remarks," _
                        & "TRDate," _
                        & "UpdatedBy," _
                        & "UpdatedDate," _
                        & "SOId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYSTEM_USER,getdate(),?)"
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 1) = .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , Me.txtSONo.Text)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 1) 'SONo
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 2) = .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , Me.cmbSupplier.Value)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 2) 'SId
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 3) = .CreateParameter(, adSmallInt, adParamInput, , Me.cmbPayTerm.Value)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 3) 'PId
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 4) = .CreateParameter(, adCurrency, adParamInput, , Me.StatusBar.Panels(3))
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 4) 'totAmt
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 5) = .CreateParameter(, adCurrency, adParamInput, , 0)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 5) 'advAmt
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 6) = .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, Me.txtPreparedBy)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 6) 'Prepared
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 7) = .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, pubVPres)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 7) 'Recommended
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 8) = .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, Me.txtApprovedBy)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 8) 'Approved
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 9) = .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, Me.txtNotedBy)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 9) 'Noted
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 10) = .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, IIf(Trim(Me.txtRemarks) = "", Null, Me.txtRemarks))
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 10) 'Remarks
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 11) = .CreateParameter(, adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , Me.mskDate.Text)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 11) 'TRDate
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set Prm(0, 0) = .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , Id)
    .Parameters.Append Prm(0, 0) 'SOId
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    MsgBox "Retval Before execute: " & RetVal      
    .Execute RetVal    
    MsgBox "Retval After execute: " & RetVal

    Call SetLastNo(33, Id)
    Call SetLastNo(34, No)
End With
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Try inserting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your sql statement. 2. Check out [How to tell if a db update was successful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878577/how-to-tell-if-a-db-update-was-successful)

Comment: @C-PoundGuru : i tested adding adExecuteNoRecords but still no luck and about set nocount on, will i insert it in my insert into query or make a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat and found that the NOCOUNT being set to ON was causing the problem, so adding `SET NOCOUNT OFF` at the start of the SQL allowed the correct record count to be returned.

The return value of -1 does make sense, if you see it as ADO telling the caller that it is not able to return the affected record count, but that is just an assumption on my part.

Here is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage) discussing the effect of setting NOCOUNT ON can have on various aspects, but mostly focussed on performance.